# How do I create an alternate Text To Speech function in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text-to-speech, wav

I am trying to create a text to speech function  in my vb application.

Th default  method of creating a text to speech :

```
Dim SAPI

SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")

SAPI.Speak(TextBox1.Text)
```

that method is inadequate for what I am doing.

Lets say I have 4 audio clips  , the names of the clips are :

1. ba.wav  `ba sound`
2. a.wav   `a sound`
3. ka.waav  `ka sound`
4. ja.wav   `ja sound`

Let us say I  now have 4 characters , these characters are :

1. µ `to represent the ba sound`
2. ö `to represent the a sound`
3. ߧ `to represent the ka sound`
4. ◊◊ `to represent the ja sound`

I have a `RichTextBox` which is `RichTextBox1`

The four characters µ,ö,ߧ,◊◊ can be entered `RichTextBox1`

I now have  this

```
Private Sub SpeakButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SpeakButton.Click

' how do i get each character in RichTextBox1 to play when this button is clicked

End Sub
```

I am not sure but I believe  that there should be  some sort of assignment of wav audio files to the corresponding character

i know that I am able to play the wav files using this method

`My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.WAV-NAME, AudioPlayMode.Background)`

so if the text in `RichTextBox1`  is `◊◊ߧµ` then the resulting speech output should sound `JAKABA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) wherein the keys are the characters and the values are the associated WAV files. Then you can simply loop through each character, look up its value in the dictionary, and play it. This is called "concatenative speech synthesis." It's fast and the result is relatively intelligible, but you'll never get anywhere near accurate speech with this method. Many years of research has gone into the field of speech synthesis and it requires a lot more than simply splicing WAV files together.

If you need accurate speech, you should try looking at other TTS engines that may support your desired language or is easily extensible. [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) may be a good choice.

Comment: thank you , I will definitely give the dictionary method a try . I would much rather create a TTS than use a ready made application though it may better than what I create . the Dictionary method sounds very interesting

Comment: I have created a dictionary with the characters as the keys and the wav files as values but I am having a few problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Dim s as String = RichTextBox1.Text
Dim fWav as String
Dim myWav As New List(Of Byte)

For x as Integer = 0 to s.Length -1
    fwav = "" 
    Select Case s.Substring(x,1)
       case "µ" : fWav = "ba.wav"
       case "ö" : fWav = "a.wav"
       case "ߧ" : fWav = "ka.wav"
       case "◊"
         If x < s.Length - 1 Then
           If s.Substring(x + 1, 1) = "◊" Then
             fWav = "ja.wav"
             x += 1
           End if  
         End if  
    End Select
    if fWav.Length > 0 Then
      if myWav.Count = 0 Then
        myWav = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fWav).ToList
      else
        myWav = Join(myWav, IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fwav).ToList)   
      endif
    endif

Next

Dim NewWav As New System.IO.FileStream("new.wav", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)

NewWav.WriteAllBytes("new.wav", myWav.ToArray)

NewWav.Close()

Dim snd As New System.Media.SoundPlayer("new.wav")
snd.Play()
```

This is the Join() function

```
Private Function Join(ByVal wavBytes As List(Of Byte), ByVal wav2 As List(Of Byte)) As List(Of Byte)

    '   add on the second file excluding its header bytes
    wavBytes.AddRange(wav2.Skip(44).Take(wav2.Count - 44))


    '   rewrite the ChunkSize and Subchunk2Size fields of the Header
    Dim chunkSize As Integer = wavBytes.Count - 8
    Dim subChunk2Size As Integer = wavBytes.Count - 44

    Dim chunkSizeBytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(chunkSize)
    Dim subChunk2SizeBytes() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(subChunk2Size)
    For i = 0 To 3
        wavBytes(4 + i) = chunkSizeBytes(i)
        wavBytes(40 + i) = subChunk2SizeBytes(i)
    Next

    Return wavBytes
End Function
```

Got this from http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?714827-RESOLVED-Concatenate-wav-files-via-byte-array

Comment: thank you , it would have taken me a long time to come up with a similar method . though the audio does not play , i am nor familiar with this method so i am unable to pinpoint the erors

Comment: i am getting this error `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.` for this line ` if x < s.Length -1 And s.substring(x+1,1) = "◊" then`

Comment: @RuchmairDixon : it's occured when it meets `◊` in the end of string .. now it's fixed and I have something (from someone else off course) ..

Comment: this line `NewWav.WriteAllBytes("new.wav", myWav.ToArray)` is being underlined as having aan error , the error is says `WriteAllBytes is not a member of System.IO.FileStream`

Comment: @RuchmairDixon .. truly I'm never doing with sounds before, but now I'm interested, so I tried to figured this out .. I'll tell you if it done ..

Comment: check it out 
i just added the example as an answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17175193/2423014

Comment: I got it to work now . the only issue remaining is that i need help using the join function  i will update my answer with the new code

Comment: how would i incorporate the join function then ? because there is horrible delay between playback